# Парсинг данных с "+" и "-"

Tags: python, парсер, requests, bs4

Парсер неправильно выводит данные за день, содержащие "+" и "-". В чём может быть проблема?

Вот мои код:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://smart-lab.ru/q/portfolio/jokerv4/8481/'
sourse = requests.get(url)
new_news = []
soup = BeautifulSoup(sourse.text, 'html.parser')
news = soup.find('table', {'csv-download-data': 'russian_shares'})
news = news.findAll('tr')
n = ""
for i in range(len(news) - 1):
    if news[i].find('a') is not None:
        if news[i + 1].find('td', {'class': 'up'}) is None:
            n = news[i + 1].find('td', {'class': 'down'}).text
        if news[i + 1].find('td', {'class': 'down'}) is None:
            n = news[i + 1].find('td', {'class': 'up'}).text
        print(n)
        w = news[i + 1].find('a').text + ":" + news[i + 1].find('td', {'class': 'price'}).text + n
        # может быть down или up исправить это
        w = w.split()
        w = ''.join(w)
        new_news.append(w)
for i in range(len(new_news)):
    print(new_news[i])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не знаю Вашей конечной цели, но возможно такой способ Вам подойдет:

```py
# Если не установлены pip install pandas lxml openpyxl

import pandas as pd

url = 'https://smart-lab.ru/q/portfolio/jokerv4/8481/'
pd.read_html(url)[1][['Название', 'Прибыль ₽', 'Изм, %']].to_excel('test.xlsx', index=False)
```

**На выходе дает:**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**UPD** Если следовать логике Вашего способа вывода данных то что-то вроде этого

```py
url = 'https://smart-lab.ru/q/portfolio/jokerv4/8481/'
df = pd.read_html(url)[1][['Название', 'Прибыль ₽', 'Изм, %']]

for row in df.iloc:
    print(*row)
    title, profit, diff = row
    # some actions with variables
```

Comment: Спасибо, а как сделать так чтобы данные записывать просто в переменную?

Comment: @Валера Куда вы будете использовать данные после получения? тоесть что делать с ними дальше?

Comment: @Валера или вам вся таблица в переменную нужна?

Comment: У меня есть бот в телеграмме. Хочу чтобы при нажатии там, у меня выводились эти данные.

Comment: То есть таблицей я не пользовался.

Comment: @Валера дополнил ответ

Comment: Огромное спасибо. Буду ещё теперь и другими библиотеками пользоваться:)

Comment: Как можно ещё также сделать с нижними таблицами?

Comment: @Валера Вместо 1 напишите тут другие циферки на пробу - и будут другие таблицы со страницы: `pd.read_html(url)[1]`

Comment: @Валера. `pd.read_html(url)[1][['Название', 'Прибыль ₽', 'Изм, %']]` в этом выражении `1` это индекс таблицы в списке таблиц находящихся на листе. только названия столбцов менять не забывайте и не дергайте на каждую таблицу парсер. Получите сказу весь список `df_list = pd.read_html(url)` и выбирайте таблицы по индексу элемента списка

Comment: Понял, спасибо большое за помощь.

Comment: @Валера, если ответ вам помог, отметьте его как принятый.